# How to check and disable one of the checkboxes in a form?

Tags: forms

I found this snippet in the code for a form (`$roles` is an array of roles).

```
$form['config_options']['roles'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => $roles,
];
// Check and disable the 'authenticated' role.
$form['config_options']['roles'][RoleInterface::AUTHENTICATED_ID] = [
  '#default_value' => TRUE,
  '#disabled' => TRUE,
];
```

What this does is to check the checkbox for the 'authenticated' role, and then disables it (so it can't be unchecked). This works.

I have a very similar requirement.  In a form I have checkboxes for a bunch of fields, where `$fields` is an array of them. The fields are from user profile. I want to check and disable the 'email' field.

Based upon the code snippet above, I think the solution should be something like this:

```
$form['config_fields']['fields'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => $fields,
];
// Check and disable the 'email' field.
$form['config_fields']['fields'][ -- What to put here? -- ] = [
  '#default_value' => TRUE,
  '#disabled' => TRUE,
];
```

However, I have no idea what to put in the selector where I've written " `-- What to put here? --`".

Based upon a comment from Clive I've tried to examine `$fields`. This is what the *devel* Default variables-dumper gives me (using short array syntax):

```
$fields = [
  …
  mail => stdClass Object (
    [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup
    [translatedMarkup:protected] => 
    [options:protected] => []
    [stringTranslation:protected] => 
    [string:protected] => Email
    [arguments:protected] => []
  )
  …
]
```

So it is a bit more complex than the example given in Clive's comment (e.g. it is an object, not an array (as implied by Clive).

So far I've tried 'Email'.

```
$form['config_fields']['fields'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => $fields,
];
// Check and disable the 'email' field.
$form['config_fields']['fields']['Email'] = [
  '#default_value' => TRUE,
  '#disabled' => TRUE,
];
```

This does not work.

Help will be appreciated.

Also, if I am barking up the wrong tree, and there exists another way to do this, I shall equally appreciate an alternative solution.

(I am using Drupal 9).

Comment: It would be the relevant array key from `$fields`. e.g. if `$fields = ['foo' => 'Foo', 'bar' => 'Bar'];`, and you want to check `Bar`, the key is `bar`

Comment: @Clive Thanks for the suggestion. I've expanded `fields` and updated the question with the expanded version.  It looks like an object, while your suggestion implies that it is an array. It is still not clear to me what to use as key. Following your suggestion, I think it should be 'Email', but 'Email' does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out that the key is simply the machine *name* of the field you want to check and disable.  This works:

```
$form['config_fields']['fields'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => $fields,
];
// Check and disable the 'mail' field.
$form['config_fields']['fields']['mail'] = [
  '#default_value' => TRUE,
  '#disabled' => TRUE,
];
```